# Integer solutions (lattice points) to arbitrary circles

Tags: diophantine-equations, circles, integer-lattices

Wolfram Alpha will provide integer solutions to arbitrary circle equations.  I'm trying to understand how it's able to calculate them, but despite a fair bit of digging I haven't found any discussion of how to get either the number of, or which, integer solutions to a given circle.  Plenty of discussion of lattice points *inside* a circle, related to the Gauss circle problem, and some discussion of circles centered on the origin, but nothing for the general case.

Wolfram Alpha can quickly determine there are $12$ integer solutions to the circle [$x^2-10 (x+y)+y^2+50 = 50$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E2%2F2-10+%28x%2By%29%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2+%3D+10%5E2%2F2) - how?

Comment: Someone should read through this paper, and figure out the exact ${\cal O}(\cdot)$ time complexity: *Felipe Cucker Pascal Koiran and Steve Smale, A Polynomial Time Algorithm for Diophantine Equations in One Variable* [PDF file](http://lara.inist.fr/bitstream/handle/2332/690/RR1997-45.pdf;jsessionid=C217F2640B9B9606C52C13171D9C13C6?sequence=1)

Comment: How did you get Wolfram alpha to provide integer solutions?

Comment: @LarsH I just dropped in the equation and it provided them, see the link in my question.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the coefficients of $x^2, \; y^2$ are $1$ and the coefficients of $x,y$ are even, this is quite easy. What you get by completing two squares is
$$  (x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 50.   $$ Fine, so define new variables, 
$$  u = x-5, \; \; \; v = y - 5,  $$ and count the (integer pair) solutions to
$$  u^2 + v^2 = 50.  $$ For each pair, return by $x = u + 5, \; \; y = v + 5.$
It is easy enough to plot these.

However, what if you had some very large target number $n$ and had to count the number of integer pair solutions to
$$  u^2 + v^2 = n?  $$
Well, if you can factor $n,$ you can make a complete list of all numbers that divide it, including $1$ and $n$ itself. Ignore the even divisors. Count the number of divisors that leave a remainder of 1 when divided by 4, call that count $C_1.$ Put another way, this is the count of $d > 0, \; \; d | n, \; \; d \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$ Next,  count the number of divisors that leave a remainder of 3 when divided by 4, call that count $C_3.$ This is the count of $d > 0, \; \; d | n, \; \; d \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ The number of integer lattice points on the circle is 
$$  4 (C_1 - C_3).$$
For $n = 50,$ the divisors are $1,2,5,10,25,50.$ So $C_1 = 3$ and $C_3 = 0,$ and the number of integer points is $4 (3-0) = 4 \cdot 3 = 12.$

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @user7530: See [the answers to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17496/11619) for more discussion.

Comment: @Jyrki, this description is Theorem 65 on page 80 of Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Leonard Eugene Dickson, (1929). Proper representations are Theorems 61 and 62 on page 76. I probably have more recent books that give the "excess of divisors" method. Dickson does some other forms with class number one in exercises on pages 80-81. Rather cute, in a footnote he points to his own 1911 proof that there are no extra discriminants of class number one to $-1,500,000.$

Comment: @WillJagy, thanks for the reference. I really should get my hands on a copy of that book :-). I've seen, e.g. Carlitz refer to it on at least couple occasions. I recently spent some time on a cute but not deep problem. Found a reference from 70s, another from the late 50s. Then in a paper Carlitz says that the result is an exercise (!) in Dickson's book :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, I sent you an email with a place to buy the Dickson book.

Comment: @WillJagy - does your method work for arbitrary circle equations, like the one I posted?  Perhaps I'm just terrible at algebra, but I can't seem to generate a $u$ and $v$ given the equation I posted, the best I can get is $(x-10)x+(y+10)y = 0$.

Comment: @dimo414: If you "complete the square" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) with the equation you gave, you get $(x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 = 50$. That's what Will is showing in the first equation he gives.