# About hypotenuse of pythagorean triple

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

The hypotenuse of any Pythagorean triple seems not to be divided by some primes such as $3, 7$. What are the others? Are there infinitely many such primes?

In other words, I am looking for number $c$ such that
$a^2 + b^2 = kc$  have no integer solutions for any positive integer $k$ and $a,b < c$.

Comment: Yes, these are the primes of the form $4n+3$ and there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions of pythagorean triples. Sir Wiles proved that for the equation $ x^{n} + y^{n} = z^{n} $ has no solutions for n larger than two.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers. I that case euclid formulas hold:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= m^2-n^2 \\
b &= 2mn \\
c &= m^2+n^2 
\end{align}
$$
where $m,n$ are positive integers.

Now use the following Fermat theorem (have a look at [Arturo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17503/34296)):

> **Theorem** (Fermat) Let $n$ be a positive integer, and write $n$ in the form $$n = 2^{\alpha}\prod_{p\equiv 1\pmod{4}} p^{\beta} \prod_{q\equiv 3 \pmod{4}} q^{\gamma}.$$
>   with $p$ and $q$ primes. Then $n$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares if and only if all the exponents $\gamma$ are even.

Since you are looking for only primes then it becomes $n = p$ such that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Look for primes that can be written as $n = 4k + 3$ with $n$ integer.