# Number of different ways that a number can be represented as the sum of two square?

Tags: number-theory

Let $r(n)$ denote the number of different ways in which a natural number $n$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares. Is there any function $f(n)$ such that $r(n) \geq n^{f(n)}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there are many $n$ for which $r(n)=0$ but $n^{f(n)} \gt 0$ for any real $f(n)$

Comment: @Frpzzd:  I don't think so because it answers the question as currently posed.

Comment: Right! Thanks! Is there any condition that we can assume for $n$ and then find $f(n)$?

Comment: @Megan:  This is given in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/number-of-integer-solutions-of-x2-y2-k).  It depends on the factorization of $n$

Comment: Got it! Thank you!