# Integer representation $x^2+y^2+p(z^2+t^2)=M$

Tags: number-theory, integers

It is clear that a number can be represented as two sums of squares [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fermats-sum-of-two-squares-theorem/). We have Cornacchia's algorithm to solve this problem efficiently. We also know how many solutions to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/number-of-integer-solutions-of-x2-y2-k).

My question is when a number can be represent as the $x^2+y^2+p(z^2+t^2)=M$ ($p$ is a prime, $x,y,z,t \in \mathbb{Z}$) and how many solutions to this. We know the answer when $M \le p$, but we have no ideal about $M>p$.